# How to clip a background on a colored text (only in css)

Tags: css

I have a product configurator on my website. The user can write a word on a clothe and a text appears on the product image.

I want to style this text to look like an embroidery. So i put a text shadow, the text color changes in function of the product color, but now, i want to put a "filter" over the color.

Constraint: i just have access to the CSS.

here's a fiddle i did:

```
  #text
{
    font-size:90px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'petit_formal_script';
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
    color:lightblue;
}

#text:after
{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-image:url('http://hdwbin.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/red-background.jpg');
    -webkit-background-clip:text;
    -moz-background-clip:text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u2to713t/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you for maybe provide an example-picture of what you want the text to look like?

Comment: try going here: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u2to713t/4/
i want the text to look like this. but the background clipped to the text :/
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Finally did it.. 
The result is not what i expected but it works.
Here's the final fiddle for the one who will try one day to do the same thing:

http://jsfiddle.net/u2to713t/13/

```
#text
{
    font-size:90px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'petit_formal_script';
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #474747;
    color:lightblue;
}

#text:before
{
     content: attr(data-text);
    position:absolute;
    left:-1px;
    top:7px;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    opacity:1.0;
    z-index: 1;
   color:transparent;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 0px;
    background:url("http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/20/1431421588-brodrwhite.png"); 
    -webkit-background-clip:text;
    -moz-background-clip:text;
     background-clip:text;



}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add background image to a transparent text with with transparent text shadow using rgba

`#text{
    font-size:90px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'petit_formal_script';
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color:transparent;
    background-image:url('http://hdwbin.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/red-background.jpg');
    -webkit-background-clip:text;
    -moz-background-clip:text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;
}`

Comment: Hello Ahmd, This solution is not possible. The color is automatically setby the user who is able to change the color of the text he wants to apply on his clothe

Answer (score 0):

is this what u mean?

```
#text {
    background: url(http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/20/1431421588-brodrwhite.png) repeat;
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    font-size:90px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'petit_formal_script';
}
```

Comment: Hello Panto Andjelic,
Not really,
I have a background image with opacity.
you can see here:  
jsfiddle.net/u2to713t/4

The problem is that i want to stack them in order to have the text color + the filter.
Thank you.

Comment: i dont think i get it sorry.I made edit but still dont understand sorry again